# Remove final slash and number in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings like these:

text-23

the-text-9

2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455

I need to remove the final -number from the string in Python (and I'm terrible with regular expressions).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming all the text you have ends with -number

```
>>> s="2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455"
>>> s.rsplit("-",1)[0]
'2011-is-going-to-be-cool'
```

or

```
>>> iwant=s.rsplit("-",1)
>>> if iwant[-1].isdigit():
...   print iwant[0]
...
2011-is-going-to-be-cool
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455'.rstrip('0123456789-')
```

Comment: depending on what OP means by "removing the final -number", a string like "2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455-554" will remove the "455" as well, since its not the final number.

Comment: Thanks Felmarri! It doesn't work if there is a number before the -number, like: "i-was-born-in-1982-543"

Comment: @ana: Exactly as ghostdog74 points out. See the other answers if they help you.

Comment: @ana: That's why you have to be very explicit in what you're trying to do when you ask a question =P

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str = re.sub(r'-[0-9]+$', '', str)
```

Comment: or `str = re.sub(r'-\d+$', '', str)`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you probably want [rpartition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rpartition#str.rpartition):

```
s1 = "text-23"
s2 = "the-text-9"
s3 = "2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455"

#If you want the final number...
print s1.rpartition("-")[2]
#23

#If you want to strip the final number and dash...
print s2.rpartition("-")[0]
#the-text

#And showing the full output...
#  - Note that it keeps the rest of your string together, unlike split("-")
print s3.rpartition("-")
#('2011-is-going-to-be-cool', '-', '455')
```

I think this is ever-so-slightly cleaner to read than `split("-", 1)`, since it is exactly what you want to do.  Outputs are near identical, except that rpartition's output includes the delimiter.

And, just for kicks, I had a look and rpartition is marginally quicker...

```
import timeit
print timeit.Timer("'2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455'.rsplit('-', 1)").timeit()
#1.57374787331
print timeit.Timer("'2011-is-going-to-be-cool-455'.rpartition('-')").timeit()
#1.40013813972

print timeit.Timer("'text-23'.rsplit('-', 1)").timeit()
#1.55314087868
print timeit.Timer("'text-23'.rpartition('-')").timeit()
#1.33835101128

print timeit.Timer("''.rsplit('-', 1)").timeit()
#1.3037071228
print timeit.Timer("''.rpartition('-')").timeit()
#1.20357298851
```

Comment: Nice solution. I tend to forget about (r)partition all the time because it is so similar to (r)split, but there are some cases where it fits so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .rsplit() method suggested by @ghostdog74 is best; however, here is another option:

```
for s in myStrings:
    offs = s.rfind('-')
    s = s if offs==-1 else s[:offs]
```